# How can I get a list of windows with Wnck, using PyGI?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, pygobject, wnck

I just started using PyGI (on Ubuntu Natty), although I have never used pygtk before.
I have used wnck in a wxPython program though, and it was easy enough to get a list of currently opened windows. From PyGI, the window list is always empty.
relevant code bits:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Wnck

while Gtk.events_pending():
    Gtk.main_iteration()
#... in my app class...
    screen = Wnck.Screen.get_default()
    wins = screen.get_windows()
```

with that, `wins == []`.
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, ptomato! How can I do that myself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call [`screen.force_update()`](http://developer.gnome.org/libwnck/stable/WnckScreen.html#wnck-screen-force-update) before `screen.get_windows()` returns list of windows. Unfortunately docs are lacking this part :(

```
In [1]: from gi.repository import Gtk, Wnck

In [2]: Gtk.main_iteration()
Out[2]: True

In [3]: screen = Wnck.Screen.get_default()

In [4]: screen.force_update()

In [5]: screen.get_windows()
Out[5]: 
[<Window object at 0x167bd20 (WnckWindow at 0x195d0e0)>,
 <Window object at 0x167bf00 (WnckWindow at 0x195d740)>,
 <Window object at 0x167bf50 (WnckWindow at 0x195d850)>]
```

Comment: Can you please share the link to available doc? I couldn't find it

Comment: Mentioned under the Examples heading: https://developer.gnome.org/libwnck/stable/getting-started.html

Comment: This does not seem to work for new windows opened since first starting the script. Is there something else that needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

In your example you have to use: `Gtk.main_iteration_do(False)` instead of `Gtk.main_iteration()`.